# add text on uptrend and downtrend

Tags: pine-script

I merged 2 rsi into 1 but when rsi cross the upper or lower band then I want to add text. I tried to add text on this

```
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
```

but its not working. here is what i want in this pic, please help me.
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/36f0e5b9072c66ec27bf25a6b0299839.png]

```
indicator(title="Darkforum RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"


plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = plot(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#f7270b)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = plot(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#fc2c10)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(#42f748, 2) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your pic, you write `High` when your rsi > 70 and `Low`when your rsi < 70, you can add this to your code (at the end) :

```
if ta.crossover(rsi,70)
    label.new(bar_index, 75, "High", color=color.new(color.white, 100), style=label.style_label_down)
if ta.crossover(30, rsi)
    label.new(bar_index, 25, "Low", color=color.new(color.white, 100), style=label.style_label_up)
```

and get :
[image]

Comment: i get error
Error at 37:5 The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects

Comment: fixed this. i remove it timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true

Comment: some time its give 2 times low or high. i want to show only 1 time in every crossover. can it possible sir?

Comment: the code use crossover and crossunder, so you will only have 1 label High or Low. I you look precisely when you have 2 Highs, you will see the RSI goes under 70 and come back over 70